# Log4net filename with date and two logging sources

Tags: log4net

I'm trying to configure a RollingFileAppender that has a filename format similar to the IIS log files - **testYYMMDD.log** - and that rolls over by UTC date.

Here is my configuration:

```
<appender name="rfDate" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="C:\Logs\test" />
    <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="false" />
    <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
    <param name="RollingStyle" value="Date" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="yyMMdd.lo\g" />
    <param name="MaxSizeRollBackups" value="7" />
    <dateTimeStrategy type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender+UniversalDateTime" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%utcdate [%t] %-6p %c - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

It works fine if there is only one source writing to this file.  However, I have two sources that I want to write to this same one file.

When the first one writes, the log file is created successfully - **test140409.log**

When the second source writes, a new log file is created - **test140409.log140409.log**

Both logging sources continue writing to their respective files.

Is there any way to have the date IN the filename, with two logging sources writing to the one log file, without it creating two files?

Comment: When you say you have two sources writing to the file, do you mean multiple loggers in the same process or two different processes?

Comment: Two separate processes, both configured with the same log4net settings to write to one log file.  I think I'm going to switch to separate log files, because I've come across articles that say that the RollingFileAppender does not support multiple sources and that the results can be unpredictable.  Also, I came across another article that states that each log4net instance has its own "date threshold" for rolling dates, so there isn't a way to prevent the file-naming issue described in my original question.

Comment: Here is one, of probably many, questions from here on SO about multiple processes writing to the same logfile.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586431/log4net-can-2-applications-write-to-the-same-log-file  The answers make some of the same points that you do.  It sounds like changing the LockingModel can help in writing, but does not address the rolling behavior.  Another suggestion would be to write to a database or to use some kind of remote logger or logging service.  Jimothy's answer has a good tip that would allow you to share the same log4net configuration amongst your processes.