# use the same instance of log4net to log into all projects

Tags: c#, log4net

I am using Log4net in c# solution , that contains 3 projects in one solution . 
I want to use the same instance of this logger to log into one file .
here is the App.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
  </configSections>

  <log4net>
    <appender name="TestAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
      <file value="C:\log\MyTestAppender.log" />
      <!--<file value="../../test/MyTestAppender.log" />-->
      <encoding value="utf-8" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <!--<rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
      <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />-->
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %level  %type.%method - %message%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="All" />
      <!-- If the following line is not included the log file will not be created even if log4net is configured with this file. -->
      <appender-ref ref="TestAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>


</configuration>
```

And i did this to log

```
private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

where should i put these information in order to log in the same log file from all projects.
Thanks a lot

Comment: How about your app.config, or web.config or whatever config you have in your projects? If you don't specify what projects you are talking about, it's hard to answer.

Comment: How do you expect the same logger to exist within 3 applications? I hope you already realized that [it would be bad to have 3 loggers access the same log file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2586431/5265292).

Comment: my solution it will create only one logger of log4net which means you use same instance of logger every time , ...please do accept answer if it worked for you

Comment: It really depends on the 3 projects... if we are talking about two class library projects being referenced by the 3rd, then its all ok, but if we talk about 3 independent applications that happen to live in the same solution, then static won't solve anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should load the configuration file in the static constructor.

Like this

```
    static LogHelper()
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(
            new System.IO.FileInfo(@"AppConfig\log4net.config"));
    }
```

The configuation file should like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <!-- Register log4net -->
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net"/>
    </configSections>
    <log4net>
        <!--log configs -->
    </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this , i mean to say create on static class and create log instance, and call log method on that static class it that will use only one log instance.

```
public static class Utility
    {
        private static ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("CommonLogger");
        public static void LogMessage(string message)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => log.Info(message));
        }
}
```

or you can also make use of `Singleton` pattern for this

```
public Class LogSingleTon
{

    private static readonly Lazy<LogSingleTon> lazy =
        new Lazy<LogSingleTon>(() => new LogSingleTon());

    public static LogSingleTon Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }
    private ILog log ;
    private LogSingleTon()
    {
        log = LogManager.GetLogger("CommonLogger")
    }
    public void LogMessage(string message)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => log.Info(message));
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I case you're using depedency injection frameworks, you could also register your Log4net logger as an (one) instance and have it injected wherever you would like to use it.

E.g. with Autofac:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// Log4net
var logger = LogManager.GetLogger("[Whatever name your would like to use for your logger]");
builder.RegisterInstance(logger);
```