# How to log to different log files for different instances using log4net?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, log4net

I'm working on a project which does this:

The main program uses quartz to schedule some jobs. In each job, it starts a console exe program. The console program invokes a method in one of the dlls based on the input parameters, say Run(). There are multiple dlls.

Now, if we log the info in event log, it works fine. However, we want to use log4net to log into files, and we want each dll has its own log files. Here is how I do it:

I have a class MyTask, which has:

```
public void SetLogFile(string name)
{
    // change the log folder for the dll
    XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy h =
    (log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
    foreach (IAppender a in h.Root.Appenders)
    {
        if (a is FileAppender)
        {
            FileAppender fa = (FileAppender)a;
            // Programmatically set this to the desired location here
            string logFileLocation = $".\\Logs\\{name}.log";

            fa.File = logFileLocation;
            fa.ActivateOptions();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Every class in the dll has to inhert from this class. So, when the console program has to invoke this SetLogFile method first to set the log file name, then invokes Run() in the dll.

This does generate different log files. However, for some reasons, it seems this generates some kind of lock.

The console program keeps running over and over, and starts jobs based on schedule. Some jobs should run 10 seconds, some should run 60 seconds, some should run 120 seconds (for now, we simply sleep # of seconds to simulate the case). However, I notice something strange. Since each dll is invoked from the console program, I can see multiple instances of the console program in task manager. I can also see the parameters they use (which decides how long it will run). But from the task manager, it seems these instances are not running parallel. They are running in order.

I'm not sure why, but my guess is that the log file is locked since the dlls are invoked from the console program. In the log4net config, I use

```
<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
```

But this seems does not solve the problem. If I let the console program run for a long time, gradually, I can see lots of instances of it (with different input parameters). But they are not 'dead', Gradually, they will exit, while more new instances will show up.

Anyone had this issue before? How to solve it? Or, maybe use another log framework? or, maybe the way I implement it is wrong? Any other suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586431/log4net-can-2-applications-write-to-the-same-log-file ? I'd say use a web service, or a database if you can for your logging, or since it's a windows app... the windows event log?

Comment: windows event log works fine. but we want to see whether log4net is better. We are not logging to the same log file with multiple instances. each dll uses its own log file. But all methods from different dlls are invoked from the same console program. This seems generating the 'lock' issue.

Comment: is there an error somewhere being thrown? A console program calling a dll that has it's own log file in it's own instance wouldn't cause locking.

Comment: It's more likely you're running into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528669/why-does-the-net-framework-lock-dlls , which is probably being flushed by the log4net implementation.

Comment: I presume there is a single instance of the console app and then multiple assemblies?  Does the console app load in multiple assemblies concurrently, or is it one console execution per assembly?